# Jmeter Webdriver test results are showing in View Results tree, but data is not showing in aggregate report

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, listener, reporting

Jmeter Webdriver test results are showing in View Results tree, but all data is not showing in aggregate report.

Aggregate report is showing #Samples and Label correctly but no other information is displaying.

I created a different webdriver sampler with out any waits, those results are showing correctly in aggregate report. Not sure if webdriver request with waits will not show data in listeners properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what is wrong without seeing your WebDriver Sampler code, double check that you have:

- `WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()` - at the beginning of the actions, which duration you want to measure
- `WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()` - at the end of the actions, which duration you want to measure

The same applies for other instances of the [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class, i.e. if you're using [`addSubResult()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#addSubResult-org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult-)

The minimal code would be something like:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)

Answer (score 0):

My intial webdriver test started with :
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() but I did not write sampleend()

Fixed the reporting issue after adding :   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd() at end of my request.